# Scringo framework app crashes in ios?

Tags: ios, scringo

I'm Facing very strange problem, my ios app crashes on my devices and simulatore, i 
    developed app on one mac and system and move source code to another mac, on new mac 
    my scringo framework showing different types of crash reports like "Terminating app due to
    uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ 
    setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key 
    closeButton.'".

```
   I done a lot of googled, but i didn't get any solution. i contacted to scringo help 
support also, didn't get any response on http://www.scringo.com/about.php
```

Comment: which version and device crashed on other system and what you have test in your system

Comment: both systems and devices configurations are same,as well as devices and simulators also

Comment: describes configuration details

Comment: os x 10.8.5 and ios7.0.4 bot my mac systems are same but rams are seperate like 2 gb and 4 gb

Comment: how do you know this crash happens the reason for scringo framewrok

Comment: value coding-compliant for the key closeButton. check your IBOutlet

Comment: what perform you made to screen through this crash happened

Comment: see below code here scringoappbannerview is the class defined by scringo but not visible in my xcode

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ScringoAppBannerView 0xd4853f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key closeButton.'

Answer (score 0):

The most likely source of this error is that something has a connection to an action or outlet called done that doesn't exist in the code for that class.